# Creating association with an existing table

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a **users** table that gets information from our identity provider **Auth0**.

How can I use Sequelize associations to make one:one relationship with my contact table.

Example: Contacts table

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Contacts = sequelize.define('profile_contacts', {
        ID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        phone: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        linkedin_profile: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    });

    return Contacts;
}
```

Comment: Here http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html

Comment: I've read the docs. I've followed the docs and it keeps returning "NULL" because the users table already exists.

Comment: can you please update your question and show how are you doing the association and where ti shows the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693578/sequelize-foreign-key-returning-as-null This is a previous post I created where I added my code and error.